# Accessing redux store in headlessJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I need to access store in headlessJS in react native to dispatch an action.

I tried

```
AppRegistry.registerHeadlessTask('didEnterRegion', (beacon) => Util.didEnterRegion.bind(beacon, store));
```

and in Util.js

```
const didEnterRegion = async (beacons, store) => {
console.log(beacons);
store.dispatch({
  type: FOUND_PLACES_FAIL,
  payload: err
});
});
```

but now I receive the beacons object as an empty object. How do I pass that object too along with the store.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, so stupid of me. 
I just had to pass the params in headlessJS.

```
AppRegistry.registerHeadlessTask('didEnterRegion', (beacon) => Util.didEnterRegion.bind(beacon, store));

const didEnterRegion = async (store, beacon) => {
console.log(beacon);
store.dispatch({
type: FOUND_PLACES_FAIL,
payload: err
});
});
```

Comment: So you can access store data from headelesJS?

Comment: Yes!  The store is accessible everywhere in the app. @rendom